# titlepage with newpage

Tags: titles, copyright

I would like to use the `\titlepage` with the `\newpage` command because I need to post a copyright note on the back of my title.

The result is, that 
1. The frontpage (with the title and my name on it) is shifted like for a doublesided print
2. A pagenumber appears on the page with the copyright note
3. Two empty pages are added after the copyright note page

How can I avoid the problems described above? Especially the two empty pages are bothering me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What do you mean by ‘two empty sides’? Two blank pages? The front page is shifted, I suppose, because of unequal left and right margins?

Comment: Normally LaTeX takes care about right pagination -- even in twoside mode. Did you `\documentclass[twoside...`?

Comment: Moreover you just describe a problem but we can't see what you are doing at all. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). As it stands your question isn't really answerable.

Comment: Yes those are two empty pages. The example is like that
\cleardoublepage\include{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage\include{mydedication}

the titlepage file is titlepage.tex and looks like that:
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace
my text here
\vspace
myname here
\newpage
my copyright text is here
\end{titlepage}

Comment: `titlepage` is just for *one* page. You can have more than one, but with the standard classes, page numbering is screwed.

Comment: Why can't you put `\newpage` after `\end{titlepage}`? You should remove the `\cleardoublepage`s, almost certainly. Let LaTeX take care of it.

Comment: Still no minimal working example to reproduce the issue. I vote to close as unclear.